# Yii2 pjax is working only the first time

Tags: php, yii2, pjax

I am using pjax with Yii2 and I have faced a problem with pjax.
All scripts are working correctly and fine only the first time and after sending a pjax request and updating the table content, scripts and pjax not working. If I remove the line `$.pjax.reload({container:'#products-table'});` all scripts are working. And also I found this solution ( [Yii2 Pjax and ActiveForm beforeSubmit not working after reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524980/yii2-pjax-and-activeform-beforesubmit-not-working-after-reload) ): " `$(document).on('ready pjax:success', function(){ // to do });` " and with it working fine BUT after adding more jquery code it stopped working again. Please if someone has the same issue please share with solution. Thanks!

```
$(document).on('ready pjax:success', function(){

    $(".product-edit-submit").on('click', function(){
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url : editUrl,
                data: {
                    id: this.id,
                    productName: productName,
                    productCost: productCost,
                    _csrf: csfr
                },
                success  : function(response) {
                    $.pjax.reload({container:'#products-table'});
                },
                error : function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
            return false;

        });
    });
```

## VIEW :

```
<?php Pjax::begin(['id' => 'products-table']); ?>
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
        .......
        </table>
<?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Change this line  `$(".product-edit-submit").on('click', function(){`

**to :**

```
 $(document).on('click', '.product-edit-submit', function () {
```

Then It will work

Answer (score 0):

if your code stops after adding extra libraries try registering it in view to make sure it will execute after all libraries included:

```
<?php
$js = <<< 'JAVASCRIPT'
$(document).on('ready pjax:success', function(){

$(".product-edit-submit").on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : editUrl,
            data: {
                id: this.id,
                productName: productName,
                productCost: productCost,
                _csrf: csfr
            },
            success  : function(response) {
                $.pjax.reload({container:'#products-table'});
            },
            error : function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
        return false;

    });
});
JAVASCRIPT;
$this->registerJs($js,\yii\web\View::POS_READY);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @mmta41 but this didn't work. The problem is coming only after pjax request is sent and table container is reloaded.

Comment: If I remove $.pjax.reload({container:'#products-table'}); all scripts are working but the table content is not updating I have to refresh the page in order to see the changes. Comments please.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why the second time scripts are not triggering.
I putted the script outside of `$(document).on('ready pjax:success', function(){ //code });`. After putting it inside of `pjax:success`, all the scripts are working again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For example, assume the following document:

```
<div id="a">
<?php Pjax::begin() ?>
  <div id="b">
  ...
  </div>
<?php Pjax::end() ?>
</div>
```

Now, when you want to handle the event of "#b", you may want to write like this:

```
<script>
$("#b").on("someEvent", function(){…});
</script>
```

But it only works for the first event. The event handler will be lost when “#b” is updated by pjax.
It won’t work for the 2nd event and after.

The script should be:

```
<script>
$("#a").on("someEvent", "#b", function(){…});
</script>
```

This will attach an event handler to “#a”, but the handler handles the event of “#b”. And because “#a” is outside the pjax area, the event handler won’t be lost when “#b” is updated by pjax.